# Cosmicmind: how to dismiss floatingViewController / return rootViewController?

Tags: cosmicmind

toolbarController?.floatingViewController = vc

to floating view controller. As expected, toolbar not showing and screen shows with full size. I want to dismiss back to rootViewController didnt achieve that.

Actually i showed apps in pagetabbar like google play and now i want to show app detail page. When user clicks app icon, app icon will animate and shows detail page and if he wants to, it will dismiss that. I used transition method first (it has animation parameter) but i want to figure out difference between floating usages etc. Is there any showcase ? Thank you for great library btw.

Answer (score 0):

to hide the `floatingViewController`, set it to `nil`. There isn't a showcase at the moment. The `transition` method is for changing the `rootViewController`. Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you for your responding, it works but  when i look in the code, before floating, it makes userInteractionEnabled to false and set views / toolbar alpha to 0.5. When i set  self.view  to nil from current view, how can i set root controller is the current one so that i will cast toolbar then reach methods :  alpha and userInteraction enabled. I want to use floating because when i use transition i loose the state. Thank you.

Comment: The interaction is disabled only because of the animation. Once the animation is done, interaction is enabled again. To get access to the toolbar functions, use the helper `toolbarController?.toolbar` property, in any function but the `viewDidLoad` because it won't be part of the view hierarchy until after that.